# IIS and PHP speed differences on same server. Hug of death

Tags: windows, php, iis

I have a website that uses PHP and hosted on a IIS server that is currently experiencing the hug of death(1000+ concurrent users). The site takes about 1 minute to load a simple php web page.
I also have the pre prod version of that site hosted on the same server with IIS but that site loads instantly.

I have my site and I have set up a test:

- example.com/test.php
- pp.example.com/test.php

the main site takes 14 seconds to load a hello world echo
the pp site takes 17ms

```
<?php

echo "hello!";

?>
```

What setting would causing this to happen as I cant work out why one would be fine and the other is super slow.

I am using PHP 7.2.2, IIS and Windows Server 2016 on the exact same server with the same IP address

Also note, when I tried a simple hello world html page, that still loaded instantly which leads me to believe that its a PHP configuration issue.

Comment: Did you review max PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS settings? (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/running-php-applications-on-iis/configure-php-process-recycling-behavior)

Comment: On which IP-Adresses is IIS listening?
Are you opening the site on the same machine or should it be done from outside, LAN / WAN ?

Comment: @SmileMZ I am listening on *. I am doing the test on the same external computer with the same network connection for both

Comment: @Gerrit I checked and that is configured at 10000 requests on both, which seems to be correct

Comment: And @jLynx, the instanceMaxRequest of the application pool is set lower, right? Another thing that you might run into is opcache fragmentation.  Look at https://github.com/rlerdorf/opcache-status and https://tideways.com/profiler/blog/fine-tune-your-opcache-configuration-to-avoid-caching-suprises. Also make sure that you run the NON thread safe version of PHP with fastcgi.

Comment: @Gerrit I am using a NTS version of PHP with FastCGI. Right now the value is the same which going off of the information from before means it will kick in before the default recycling as it needs to be the same or lower.

Comment: @jLynx, yes preferably instanceMaxRequest should be lower. Maybe the opcache thing then.

Comment: And of course the max number of instances in the application pool.

Comment: Does your server has access to the internet (outbound), if not, probably there is something in the code that tries to reach the internet.

Comment: Please look at the example I gave @on8tom there is nothing there that calls any external resource. Also yes, it does have internet outbound